# Constantly getting "Project Files Changed" messages in PyCharm, even though I haven't changed any of the files in my project

Tags: python, pycharm

Pretty much what it says in the title- I am constantly getting "Project Files Changed" messages in PyCharm. The exact message is:

> Project components were changed externally and cannot be reloaded:
>
> RunManager
>
> Would you like to reload project?

For example, Alt-Tabbing out of PyCharm for a few seconds and then Alt-Tabbing back in is likely to generate the message. It usually doesn't occur unless I switch to another application, although sometimes it does anyways.

Kinda stumped. Anybody seen this before?

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm getting this without using OneDrive, so really have no idea why it's occurring...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by turning off "***Synchronize files on frame activation***" in *Settings --> Apperance and Behaviour --> System Settings --> Synchronization*. The problem happens when your project use symlinks or a network file system...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PyCharm and OneDrive don't work well together. I moved my project folder out of the OneDrive hierarchy and everything settled down.